# Add target with different metrics path than job metrics path

Tags: prometheus

I have a job definition as follows:

```yaml
  - job_name: 'My-Service'
    metrics_path: '/api/my-service/actuator/prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:        
    - targets: ['1xx.xxx.xx.x7']
      labels:
        application: My-Service
        instance: DEV      
 
#For next target, I want to use the same job group as the target before, but use a different metrics path for it.
 
    - targets: ['1xx.xxx.xx.x7'] #it's the same server IP, but let's say I want to check `/dev/my-service/actuator/prometheus` instead
      labels:
        application: My-Service
        instance: instance#2
```

Can I have have targets with different `metrics_path` for a job group? Some targets can use the `metrics_path` defined for the job but is it possible that one or more targets use their own metrics_path?

I tried consulting the documentation but didn't find anything related to this.

Comment: Straight away - no: `metrics_path` is specified only on the job level. You probably can use some workaround with `relabel_config` and `__metrics_path__`, but why would you? Add a second job and specify `metrics_path` there.

Comment: I see. My intention was to have in Prometheus UI a single job with multiple targets (and specify for some targets to use a different metrics_path) but I understand that's not really possible without over complicating it. I ended up creating a new job. Thanks for your reply.